# Object-Oriented Programming in Love2D(Lua)

Tags: oop, lua, love2d

I got interested in Love2D and Lua and decided to give it a try.

So in order to get familiar both with Lua and Love2D, I code out an easy sample:

Project Structure:

```
demo
  |-ball.lua
  |-main.lua
```

---

ball.lua

```
Ball = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    xSpeed = 0,
    ySpeed = 0,
    ballRadius = 0,
    r = 0,
    g = 0,
    b = 0
}

function Ball:new(x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed, ballRadius, r, g, b)
    t = {
        x = x,
        y = y,
        xSpeed = xSpeed,
        ySpeed = ySpeed,
        ballRadius = ballRadius, 
        r = r,
        g = g,
        b = b
    }
    setmetatable(t, self)
    self.__index = self
    return t
end

function Ball:move() 
    self.x = self.x + self.xSpeed
    self.y = self.y + self.ySpeed
end

function Ball:changeColor() 
    self.r = love.math.random(0, 255)
    self.g = love.math.random(0, 255)
    self.b = love.math.random(0, 255)
    print('color: ' .. self.r .. ' ' .. self.g .. ' ' .. self.b)
end

function Ball:checkEdges() 
    if self.x + self.ballRadius > love.graphics.getWidth() or self.x - self.ballRadius < 0 then 
        self.xSpeed = self.xSpeed * -1
        Ball:changeColor()
    end
    if self.y + self.ballRadius> love.graphics.getHeight() or self.y - self.ballRadius < 0 then 
        self.ySpeed = self.ySpeed * -1
        Ball:changeColor()
    end
end

function Ball:show() 
    love.graphics.setColor(self.r, self.g, self.b)
    love.graphics.ellipse('fill', self.x, self.y, self.ballRadius)
end
```

---

main.lua

```
require "ball"
local ball = nil
local x, y

function love.load()
    x = love.graphics.getWidth() / 2
    y = love.graphics.getHeight() / 2
    ball = Ball:new(x, y, 2, 3.5, 20, 255, 255, 255)
end

function love.update(dt) 
    Ball.move(ball)
    Ball.checkEdges(ball)
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    if key == 'escape' then 
        love.event.quit()
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0)
    Ball.show(ball)
end
```

so basically it's just a ball bouncing around when it hits the edges.
Everything seems fine except for the `function Ball:changeColor()`
I want the ball to change color everytime it hits the edges, but this isn't working.
is it something wrong with the `function changeColor()` ?

here's a snapshot of the demo:

[image: 1]

the function did trigger and the rgb color values did change, but the ball itself didn't change color, any help is appreciated!

Comment: don't use love2d please :-(, use solar2d or even better gideros instead, you will have a ton of goodies! that is my personal opinion though

Comment: Inside `Ball:checkEdges` invoke the function as `self:changeColor()` instead of `Ball:changeColor()`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That was another mistake, got it working after changing this and the changeColor function, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest mistake is the color definition by itself.
The range of colors goes from 0 (zero) to 1.
So change...

```
function Ball:changeColor() 
    self.r = love.math.random(0, 255)
    self.g = love.math.random(0, 255)
    self.b = love.math.random(0, 255)
    print('color: ' .. self.r .. ' ' .. self.g .. ' ' .. self.b)
end
```

...to...

```
function Ball:changeColor() 
    self.r = love.math.random()
    self.g = love.math.random()
    self.b = love.math.random()
    print('color: ' .. self.r .. ' ' .. self.g .. ' ' .. self.b)
end
```

It should than printing out...

```
color: 0.064632309279245 0.45080402957018 0.39887099192605
```

**Object-Oriented Programming**

You assign a ball with `Ball:new()` but in further code you dont use the assigned methods with `ball`.
To give the method the ball as argument the `:` is used.
I give you an corrected version to show what i mean.
My colored ball is named `cball` here ;-)

```
-- main.lua
require "ball"

function love.load()
    x = love.graphics.getWidth() / 2
    y = love.graphics.getHeight() / 2
    cball = Ball:new(x, y, 27, 27, 200, 0, 0, 0)
end

-- When object is assigned you reach the desired function with the :
-- So use it...
function love.update(dt) 
    cball:move() -- Use assigned method with cball as first argument
    cball:checkEdges() -- Same here
end

-- Checking if key is released avoids repeating keys ;-)
function love.keyreleased(key)
    if key == 'escape' or key == 'q' then 
        love.event.quit()
    end
    if key == 'r' then
        love.event.quit('restart')
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setBackgroundColor(.125, .125, .25)
    cball:show() -- Same here
end
```

Last thing is ball.lua is not really designed as a require for Lua.
Your ball Lua returns nothing.
Therefore a second require dont do the same as the first require.
Example for a good design...

```
-- ball.lua start with...
local Ball = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    xSpeed = 0,
    ySpeed = 0,
    ballRadius = 0,
    r = 1,
    g = 0,
    b = 0
}
-- Than all function/method defining for Ball and last line do
return Ball
```

After that it loads every time (first from file and than from `package.loaded.ball`) correctly.
Moreover that design fact you can do than directly...

```
-- Ball = require('ball')
function love.load()
    x = love.graphics.getWidth() / 2
    y = love.graphics.getHeight() / 2
    cball = require('ball'):new(x, y, 27, 27, 20, 0, 0, 0)
end
```

And as a side effect the options you give in `new()` take all affect.
Another side effect is that you can do after the...

```
cball=require('ball'):new(...)
```

...a...

```
newball=cball:new(...)
```

( The three dots are placeholder for the options )
...to make another (x, y, speedx, speedy, radius, color) independent child (ball) from the child that `require('ball')` <--<< The parent Object.

Comment: Thanks! after carefully checking the documentation, found out that rgb values has to be 0 to 1, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Than you are ready for the OOP Part now.